# Not Authorized to access X on type Y from Amplify graphQL using Federated Identity Unauthorized user role

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using Amplify for a Web application (app A) but I have another node.js application (app B) that I want to use to write some data to the DynamoDB tables. App B has no frontend, therefore, I need app B to be able to have an unauthorized access (or find a way to authenticate in the backend.

I have done the following:

- Initialised Amplify
- Set up a Cognito Applicatoin Pool
- Configured various policies on the unauth role that is listed in team-provider-info.json
- Attached the unauth role to the Federated Identity Policy
- Tried both aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS" and "IAM"
- Set the auth rules to public on models
- Ran amplify update auth to set unauthenticated access

Yet, i still get an error "Not Authorized to access listPersonalInfos on type Query" in both Amplify CLI and when using queries in AppSync console.

Below is my Auth Resolver VTL and CloudWatch logs

**Auth Resolver VTL**

```
## [Start] Authorization Steps. **
$util.qr($ctx.stash.put("hasAuth", true))
#set( $isAuthorized = false )
#set( $primaryFieldMap = {} )
#if( $util.authType() == "API Key Authorization" )

#end
#if( $util.authType() == "IAM Authorization" )
  #set( $adminRoles = ["ap-southeast-2_YNRFmtdr2_Full-access/CognitoIdentityCredentials","ap-southeast-2_YNRFmtdr2_Manage-only/CognitoIdentityCredentials"] )
  #foreach( $adminRole in $adminRoles )
    #if( $ctx.identity.userArn.contains($adminRole) && $ctx.identity.userArn != $ctx.stash.authRole && $ctx.identity.userArn != $ctx.stash.unauthRole )
      #return($util.toJson({}))
    #end
  #end
$util.unauthorized()
#end
#if( $util.authType() == "User Pool Authorization" )
  #if( !$isAuthorized )
    #set( $staticGroupRoles = [{"claim":"cognito:groups","entity":"GoThriveAdmin"}] )
    #foreach( $groupRole in $staticGroupRoles )
      #set( $groupsInToken = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get($groupRole.claim), []) )
      #if( $groupsInToken.contains($groupRole.entity) )
        #set( $isAuthorized = true )
        #break
      #end
    #end
  #end
  #if( !$isAuthorized )
    #set( $authFilter = [] )
    #set( $ownerClaim0 = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("sub"), null) )
    #set( $currentClaim1 = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("username"), $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:username"), null)) )
    #if( !$util.isNull($ownerClaim0) && !$util.isNull($currentClaim1) )
      #set( $ownerClaim0 = "$ownerClaim0::$currentClaim1" )
      #if( !$util.isNull($ownerClaim0) )
        $util.qr($authFilter.add({"owner": { "eq": $ownerClaim0 }}))
      #end
    #end
    #set( $role0_0 = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("sub"), null) )
    #if( !$util.isNull($role0_0) )
      $util.qr($authFilter.add({"owner": { "eq": $role0_0 }}))
    #end
    #set( $role0_1 = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("username"), $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:username"), null)) )
    #if( !$util.isNull($role0_1) )
      $util.qr($authFilter.add({"owner": { "eq": $role0_1 }}))
    #end
    #if( !$authFilter.isEmpty() )
      $util.qr($ctx.stash.put("authFilter", { "or": $authFilter }))
    #end
  #end
#end
#if( !$isAuthorized && $util.isNull($ctx.stash.authFilter) )
$util.unauthorized()
#end
$util.toJson({"version":"2018-05-29","payload":{}})
## [End] Authorization Steps. **
```

**CloudWatch Logs**

```
{
    "logType": "RequestMapping",
    "path": [
        "listPersonalInfos"
    ],
    "fieldName": "listPersonalInfos",
    "resolverArn": "arn:aws:appsync:ap-southeast-2:771661204178:apis/6pu5wf3wvfcr7dh3zribqhp6ua/types/Query/resolvers/listPersonalInfos",
    "functionName": "QuerygetPersonalInfoauth0Function",
    "requestId": "1817ebd7-80d3-48da-93d3-471f37aa665a",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {},
        "prev": {
            "result": {}
        },
        "stash": {
            "authRole": "arn:aws:sts::771661204178:assumed-role/amplify-talentui-dev-122653-authRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials",
            "conditions": [],
            "connectionAttributes": {},
            "fieldName": "listPersonalInfos",
            "hasAuth": true,
            "metadata": {
                "dataSourceType": "AMAZON_DYNAMODB",
                "apiId": "6pu5wf3wvfcr7dh3zribqhp6ua"
            },
            "tableName": "PersonalInfo-6pu5wf3wvfcr7dh3zribqhp6ua-dev",
            "typeName": "Query",
            "unauthRole": "arn:aws:sts::771661204178:assumed-role/amplify-talentui-dev-122653-unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials"
        },
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": true,
    "errors": [
        "Not Authorized to access listPersonalInfos on type Query"
    ],
    "parentType": "Query",
    "graphQLAPIId": "6pu5wf3wvfcr7dh3zribqhp6ua",
    "functionArn": "arn:aws:appsync:ap-southeast-2:771661204178:apis/6pu5wf3wvfcr7dh3zribqhp6ua/functions/2zc46rgvzjgn3osvltkfuz4g3y"
}
```

Comment: I noticed the "API Key Authorization" condition in the resolver was empty. So, in AppSync functions, I found the resolver and updated that to authenticate the request like this ...
```#if( $util.authType() == "API Key Authorization" )
    #set( $isAuthorized = true )
#end```
...
Then I set the default auth to API Key and the query worked in AppSync queries, but only in AppSync. 

This still doesn't work from my app as this code is auto generated. 

How do I update the auto generated VTL? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue. Although I was setting the Default authorization mode in Amplify and/or AppSync settings combined with the public authRules directive in my model, this wasn't working.

This is what I did to fix it:

- Go to Amplify Console
- Open the Data tab from the menu
- Click on the model you need to apply the auth rules to
- In the Model window that opens on the right, add the auth rules you need (see **IMAGE1** below for my example:
- Save and Deploy
- Run `amplify pull` in your amplify cli app

**IMAGE1**

[image]

This created the following model auth directives in my code:

`@model @auth(rules: [{allow: public, operations: [create, update, read]}, {allow: private, operations: [create, update, read], provider: iam}, {allow: owner}, {allow: private}])`

I also added Auth.signIn() to my code and set the graphQL query authMode to AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS is show below:

```
   try {
        await Auth.signIn(process.env.USERNAME, process.env.PASSWORD);
   } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing in', error);
   }

   const result = await API.graphql<GraphQLQuery<ListPersonalInfosQuery>>({ 
       query: queries.listPersonalInfos,
       authMode: GRAPHQL_AUTH_MODE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
  }) as { data: ListPersonalInfosQuery; errors: any[] };
```

I now have access to the DynamoDB tables from App B. This is not using unauthenticated access but it worked. I'm sure there is a way to access using an unauth method as it's an option in the `amplify add|update auth` and there are unauth user roles created by default. If anyone finds a way I'd be interested to know how.